# Create own / custom class object

Tags: swift, function, class, object, struct

Is it possible to create my own object that can be chosen? For example in a function:

```
struct MyCustomType {
let id = 178
let reg = Expression<String?>(“reg”)

}


func runThis(enter: MyCustomType)
{
   print(enter)
}
```

Basically when calling runThis function I want to have a choice of id or reg. not the value of it but to chose from Id and reg like this:

```
runThis(enter: id)
//print 178
```

Comment: basically you want to use Generic values ?

Comment: Basically I want to have a choice to enter in to my function rather than generic. So for example you can only chose (this, that, then). One could be a date, one an Int and one a String.

Comment: you answer your own question actually , you want to choice generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your end goal is but you could use KeyPath here

```
struct MyCustomType {
    let id = 178
    let reg = "Expression<String?>(“reg”)"
    let date = Date()

    func runThis<T>(enter: KeyPath<MyCustomType, T>)
    {
        print(self[keyPath: enter])
    }
}
```

Example

```
let x = MyCustomType()

x.runThis(enter: \.id)
x.runThis(enter: \.reg)
x.runThis(enter: \.date)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for, KeyPath!